# call to a member function prepare() on a non-object even having PDO object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have below connection code :

```
$this->connectionString = 'mysql:host=' . db_config_DBConfig::$MySQLserverName . ';dbname=' . db_config_DBConfig::$MySQLdbName . ';port=' . db_config_DBConfig::$MySQLport .';connect_timeout=15';
    $this->connection = new PDO($this->connectionString, db_config_DBConfig::$MySQLuserName, db_config_DBConfig::$MySQLpassCode);
    $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

After doing this :

```
 $this->connection->prepare("CALL CreateRecord('testingRecord')")
```

It gives me below error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
```

When I print the object using var_dump it gives me this :

```
object(db_mysql_DBConnect)#1 (3) { ["connectionString":"db_mysql_DBConnect":private]=> string(70) "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testingrecord;port=3306;connect_timeout=15" ["connection"]=> object(PDO)#2 (0) { } ["assocData":"db_mysql_DBConnect":private]=> array(0) { } }
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: What is between the brackets? What is `$this`?

Comment: Btw `db_config_DBConfig` seems not to be a proper class name ;)

Comment: How comes you have `$this->connection = new PDO` but dump says `db_mysql_DBConnect`?

Comment: I have got it resolved now. I double check my implementation and found that I was applying prepare of singleton class object, instead of connection string (which is connect in this case). Thanks to all for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the PDO constructor failed because of wrong connection credentials. Pass `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` directly to the constructor to make the connection trigger an exception if the connection fails:

```
$this->connection = new PDO(
    $this->connectionString,
    db_config_DBConfig::$MySQLuserName,
    db_config_DBConfig::$MySQLpassCode,
    array (
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE =>  PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    )
);
```

Comment: I highly doubt it if the call to `$this->connection->setAttribute` immediately after the constructor isn't failing. OP says it doesn't fail until he calls `prepare`. I'm thinking there may be missing intervening lines.